# Scrolling while the mouse happens to be on a range slider changes the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the code below for range sliders on my website, everything alright but scrolling up/down while the mouse happens to be **on a slider** changes the value of the bar. This may cause unintended changes, and the users may not even notice that the value is changing, if he/she simply wants to scroll.

This problem happens only with Windows and Firefox (For example, Mac with Firefox acting different).

The code (credit for [Sean Stopnik](https://codepen.io/seanstopnik) from codepen):

```js
var rangeSlider = function(){
  var slider = $('.range-slider'),
      range = $('.range-slider__range'),
      value = $('.range-slider__value');
    
  slider.each(function(){

    value.each(function(){
      var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
      $(this).html(value);
    });

    range.on('input', function(){
      $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

```css
.range-slider {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 13px 0px;
}

.range-slider__range {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: calc(100% - (73px));
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #d7dcdf;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2c3e50;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
    background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2c3e50;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}
.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
    background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range:active::-moz-range-thumb {
    background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__value {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #2c3e50;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.range-slider__value:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: -7px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid #2c3e50;
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    content: '';
}

#info {
    margin: 20px -1px;
    font-size: 21px;
}
#data_value {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-size: 19px;
}

#CurrentCost, #Target_sidebar, #Target, #CurrentCost_sidebar {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#regiration_form fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}

input:invalid {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px red;
}

input:focus:invalid {
    outline: none;
}

.row.radio-scope {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.step_text {

    margin-left: 10px;
}

.progress-bar {
    background-color: #30424C;
}

.slider_row {
    margin: 25px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #d7dcdf;
}

.slider {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.name {
    margin-top: 3px;
}


::-moz-range-track {
    background: #d7dcdf;
    border: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-outer {
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="250" min="0" max="500" step="50">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="400" min="0" max="500">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>
```

I tried to find a solution on [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range), that page mentions nothing about mouse scrolling, and on that page, when I scroll while my mouse is on a slider, the page scrolls and the slider value doesn't change, as expected.

Is it possible to fix that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$(".range-slider").bind("mousewheel", function() {
    return false;
});
```

That should stop the behavior.  From there you could maybe look into bubbling if you want it to still scroll the page.

Comment: Still not fix that problem on Windows 10 with Firefox 55.0.1 (64 bit)

Comment: Sorry, I can't duplicate the issue. Even in Firefox on Windows 10 1703.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".range-slider").bind("wheel", function() {
    $(".range-slider").blur();
});
```

Use the "wheel" event instead of mousewheel.  Mousewheel does not work with firefox.

the .blur() will force document to lose focus on the input element and the scrolling will go back to scrolling the document.

Answer (score 0):

## Modern JavaScript

One would expect `.preventDefault()` to work here, and it does prevent the input value from changing. However it doesn't allow the page to scroll. For that, `.blur()` seems to be the solution. Here's a clean TypeScript snippet:

```
rangeInputElement.addEventListener("wheel", (e: WheelEvent) => {
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) e.target.blur();
});
```